# Can we pass session scope list in jsp to a do get url servlet request?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a JSP which has a session scope list from one servlet. Now I am calling another servlet through a doget url and want to pas that list. Is that possible to do? Here is my jsp code:

```
 <display:table name="sessionScope.ActivationDetailList"
                        id="ActivationDetailReport" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="ascending"
                        pagesize="<%= recordsPerPage %>" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
                        requestURI="/activationDetail.do" export="true"
                        class="data_table width_full" style="margin-left:20px;">

                        <%-- <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="true" /> 
                        <display:setProperty name="export.excel" value="true" />   
                        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="ActivationDetailReport.xls" />   
                        <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="ActivationDetailReport.csv" />               
                        <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="ActivationDetailReport.xml" /> --%> 
                         --%><display:column property="creationDate" title="Request Start Date" />
                        <display:column property="plan" title="Plan" />
                        <display:column property="txnCount" title="Total" />
                        <display:column property="user" title="User ID" />
                        <display:column property="activationType" title="Activation Type" />
                        <display:column property="status" title="Transaction Status" />
                        <display:column property="product" title="Product" />

                    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom"/>
                        <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="true" /> 
                        <display:setProperty name="export.excel" value="true" /> 
                        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="ActivationDetailReport.xls" />
                        <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="ActivationDetailReport.csv" />  
                        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="ActivationDetailReport.xls" />   
                        <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="ActivationDetailReport.xml" />
                        </display:table> 
                    <img src="ChartViewer?list=ActivationDetailList"  border=0 usemap="#imageMap">`enter code here`
```

Comment: Session scoped is not limited to a servlet... it is limited to session!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO need to pass the list again in url because you can get this list from session in another servlet as it was in the session on previous page/servlet/jsp...

Please Remember : we can't pass the list or any instance(Object) in url, we can just pass parameters in url...